# Pass localStorage input data to next page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to pass over the user name from the checkout page to the Order Finished page. User types in his name in a input field with id="v65-onepage-billfirstname". However, the next page is returning [object] [object].

on checkout page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var x = document.getElementById('v65-onepage-billfirstname').value;
localStorage.setItem('x', $('fname').val());
});
```

order finished page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = $("fname").val(localStorage.getItem('x'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id='result'></span>
```

I need to pass on the user's name so I can say something like: Thank you, David!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, `$('selector).val('whatever')` returns jQuery object. Any object by default return `[object Object]` when called with `toString` method, and that’s what probably happens when assigned to `innerHTML`. `val()` (without args) return actual value.

Try like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('x')
    $("fname").val(x);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = x;
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = $("fname").val(localStorage.getItem('x')).val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately now it's returning as undefined. Still not sure why.

Comment: I don’t know what the value of `'x'` is.

Comment: That'd be the customer's name that he typed at the checkout page. So for each customer the X value will be different (his name)

Comment: Here: `localStorage.setItem('x', $('fname').val());`—what is the value of `$('fname').val()`? Also, you assign `var x = document.getElementById('v65-onepage-billfirstname').value;` but never use `x`.

Comment: I understand. I only need the X value, which is 'v65-onepage-billfirstname'. Maybe localStorage.setItem('x', 'x'); ?

Comment: That would set value of `'x'` in the localStorage.What is element `fname`? Is this custom HTML tag?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `fname` into `localStorage` i don't see what `fname` is maybe you should do `localStorage.setItem('x', x);` if `document.getElementById('v65-onepage-billfirstname').value` is de value you want.